# wait for node server to start up in php

Tags: php, node.js, ffmpeg

I have a php script which does the following:

1. Start peerflix (node server)
2. Get PID
3. FFProbe* the server (http://127.0.0.1:8888)

All of this is done in PHP but there is a slight issue. It seems that after having received the PID, the server is not fully initialized yet, or so it seems. The problem is that `FFProbe` cannot probe the server. In other words, it's not accessible at the time of probing.

What are some possibilities to probe the server when it is actually initialized? I don't want to use the arbitrary `sleep()` method because waiting for 2 seconds on a slow vagrant machine is now the same as waiting for 2 seconds on a blazing vast server.

FFProbe throws an exception when it can't probe the server. Perhaps use a `try-catch` and return back to the `try` if an exception is thrown? How would I implement that?

*FFProbe is a companion of FFMpeg to get the information of a video file such as duration and codec.

Comment: Can you wait for output from the node server? Many node servers have a ready output like 'listening on port 1234'

Comment: @RandyKamradtSr. how would I do that?

Comment: when you start the node process, you should have access to the stdout. Read that until you get a line that matches what you expect.